# Combining two rates of change in differential calculus

Tags: calculus

Question: Given that the volume of a regular tetrahedron, all of whose sides are *t*, is $V=\frac{1}{12}t^3\sqrt2$, find the rate of increase of the surface area when the volume is $144\sqrt2 cm^3$ and is increasing at a rate of $12cm^3s^-1$

What I've done so far:

- Solved for t, $t=12cm$
- Found $\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{t^2}{2\sqrt2}$
- Found Surface Area (A)=$\sqrt3t^2$
- $A'=2\sqrt3t$
- Substituted side length of 12 into A' and $\frac{dV}{dt}$ but left me with confusion because of the quoted increase of volume rate being $12cm^3s^-1$.

What I'm struggling with:

- Combining the rate with respect to time with the rate with respect to length.
- Where does the rate of increase for volume come into it? I cannot for the life of me figure out where $12cm^3s^-1$ comes from.

Comment: I would approach this by considering the time derivative of the surface area $A$:
$$
\frac{d A}{ dT} = \frac{d A}{d V} \frac{dV}{dT}
$$
We know that $\frac{dV}{dT} = 12~\frac{\text{cm}^3}{\text{s}}$, now we only need to find $\frac{dA}{dV} = \left( \frac{dV}{dA} \right)^{-1}$. Taking the side length $t$ in, we have
$$
\frac{dV}{dA} = \frac{dV}{dt} \frac{dt}{dA} = \frac{ dV/dt  }{ dA / dt }
$$
notice that the lower-case $t$ is the side length, and $T$ is time.

Answer (score 1):

Note: To make things clearer, I'll use $s$ instead of $t$ for side length (to use $t$ for time.) I'll also ignore the units.

You have $V = \frac{1}{12}s^3\sqrt{2}$, $\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} = 12$ and $A_s = \sqrt{3}s^2$ (given). You correctly calculated that $V = 144\sqrt{2} \iff s = 12$. From here, there are two steps: using the rate of change of volume to find the rate of change of side length, and then, using that in order to find the rate of change of surface area (desired).

First, you need to find $\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt}$. Using the Chain Rule, you get:

$$\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm ds}\cdot\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}$$

Using $\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm ds} = \frac{1}{4}s^2\sqrt{2}$, $s = 12$, and $\frac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dt} = 12$, this becomes

$$12 = \frac{1}{4}(12)^2\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt} \iff \frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{12}{36\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{6} \tag{1}$$

Next, using the Chain Rule for $A_s $, you get:

$$\frac{\mathrm dA_s}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\mathrm dA_s}{\mathrm ds}\cdot\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt}$$

Using $\frac{\mathrm dA_s}{\mathrm ds} = 2\sqrt{3}s$, $s = 12$, and $\frac{\mathrm ds}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}$ from $(1)$, this becomes

$$\frac{\mathrm dA_s}{\mathrm dt} = 2\sqrt{3}(12)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}$$

$$\boxed{\frac{\mathrm dA_s}{\mathrm dt} = 4\sqrt{6}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$V = \frac{1}{12}\sqrt2 t^3 \implies t = \bigg(\frac{12V}{2^{1/2}}\bigg)^{1/3}$

> $$t^2 = {72^{1/3}V^{2/3}}$$

$A = \sqrt3t^2 = 3^{1/2}\cdot{72^{1/3}\cdot V^{2/3}}$ $$$$

$\frac{dA}{dt} = 3^{1/2}\cdot 72^{1/3}\cdot \frac{2}{3}V^{1/3}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}$
$$$$

$\frac{dA}{dt} = 2\cdot3^{-1/2}\cdot (3^22^3)^{1/3}\cdot(144\sqrt2)^{1/3}12 = 24\cdot3^{1/6}\cdot2(3^2\cdot2^{9/2})^{1/3}$ $$$$

$\frac{dA}{dt} = 24\cdot3^{5/6}\cdot2\cdot2^{3/2} =96\cdot3^{5/6}\cdot2^{1/2}$

> $$\frac{dA}{dt} = 96\sqrt2 \cdot3^{5/6}\ \ \text{cm}^2\text{/s}$$